# Function with arrays and single arguments

Tags: php

I had function simple function:

```
public function getGame($id_player)
{
    $query = "SELECT id_game FROM players_games WHERE id_player = ?";
    $result = $this->db->query($query, array($id_player));
    return $result->current()['id_game'];
}
```

I always used a single `id_player` and return from it one `id_game`.
And thats how I was using it:

```
$game= $element->getGame($id_player);
$gameName = $game['name'];
```

Now I have a array of `id_players` and I need to return this array of `id_players` and array of `id_games`, although I want to use this function for single `id_player` too (with returning `id_player` and `id_game`).

How to change this function for that and how to use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize something similar to this:

```
public function getGame($id_player)
{
    if ( is_array($id_player) )
    {
        $query = "SELECT id_game FROM players_games WHERE id_player IN (?)";
        $result = $this->db->query($query, array(implode(',', $id_player));

        $ids = array();
        while ( $row = $result->fetch() )
        {
            $ids[] = $row['id_game'];

        }
        return $ids;
    }
    else
    {
        $query = "SELECT id_game FROM players_games WHERE id_player = ?";
        $result = $this->db->query($query, array($id_player));
        return $result->current()['id_game'];
    }
}
```

This should do it for you.

Comment: Could you tell me how to return a array in this function with id_players and id_games? And how to use them? Its Zend db.